# Connect to a WPA2-Enterprise Connection via CLI (no desktop)

Tags: 12.10, wireless, server, wpa2

I've finally installed the drivers for my wireless adapter, however, I can't seem to find anything explaining out to connect to a WPA2-Enterprise connection.  I've found many WPA/WEP/WPA2 explanations, however, these don't solve my situations.

Is there any way to do this?  I'm currently CLI only, thanks!

Answer (score 25):

You can use `nmcli`

```
# nmcli con add type wifi ifname wlan0 con-name CONNECTION_NAME ssid SSID
# nmcli con edit id CONNECTION_NAME
nmcli> set ipv4.method auto
nmcli> set 802-1x.eap peap
nmcli> set 802-1x.phase2-auth mschapv2
nmcli> set 802-1x.identity USERNAME
nmcli> save
nmcli> activate
```

You may also need to add

- `nmcli> set 802-1x.password PASSWORD`
- `nmcli> set 802-1x.anonymous-identity ANONYMOUS-IDENTITY`
- `nmcli> set wifi-sec.key-mgmt wpa-eap`

Comment: I successfully used this answer to connect to [Eduroam](https://www.eduroam.org/) from the console on someone's messed-up Ubuntu 14/16 laptop that couldn't start Gnome and didn't have `wpa_supplicant` installed (user had turned off laptop while `do-release-upgrade` was running from 14 to 16, and their home directory was on a full read-only `ext2` partition due to somebody having "set up Linux" for them in a shop without knowing what he was doing).  I needed to run `/etc/init.d/network-manager start` first, and needed to set `802-1x.anonymous-identity` as well as `identity`, both to Eduroam ID.

Answer (score 3):

[wpa_supplicant](http://hostap.epitest.fi/wpa_supplicant/) is the answer. It supports WPA-Enterprise and several EAP methods. I connect to my home network by executing:

```
wpa_supplicant -i wlan0 -B -c /path/to/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

[Here](http://hostap.epitest.fi/gitweb/gitweb.cgi?p=hostap.git;a=blob_plain;f=wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf) is an example of configuration file. It's all about configuring this file to match your connection.

Answer (score 2):

None of the answers here worked for me, and after several attempts with `nmcli`, I eventually gave up and used the Ubuntu 18.04 network interface to create a connection and the I copied it over to the other computer.  Here are the steps I followed:

1. Create the network connection within the Ubuntu network connection GUI.
2. Copy the new connection from `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/` on my local compute over to the headless server.
3. Edit the MAC ID of the connection to match the interfaces from `ifconfig`.
4. Update the permissions of the copied file with:

```
chmod 0600 new_connection
chmod root:root new_connection
```

5. Restart the network manager

```
systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

For those of you that don't want to manually create the network connection in the GUI, you can modify the following network connection

```
[connection]
id=new_connection
uuid=axxxxf1f-xxxx-494c-980a-xxxxxxxxxxx
type=wifi
permissions=

[wifi]
mac-address=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
mac-address-blacklist=
mode=infrastructure
ssid=some_wifi_ssid

[wifi-security]
key-mgmt=wpa-eap

[802-1x]
eap=peap;
identity=redacted_username
password=redacted_password
phase2-auth=mschapv2

[ipv4]
dns-search=
method=auto

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
dns-search=
method=auto
```